# Align in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-alignment

I'm having trouble understanding `align`.
I tried running the following:

```
section .data
align 4
xs: dw 0xA1A2
ys: db 0xB1, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0xB4
```

and see what each byte would be, I expected it to be a contiguous block in memory as follows:

```
           for instance:    4      5    6    7     8    9     A     B
    (addr divisible by 4):[0xA2, 0xA1, 0x0, 0x0, 0xB1, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0xB4]
```

In order to make the address of ys divisible by 4
Instead it was more like:

```
                            4      5    6      7     8    9     
    (addr divisible by 4):[0xA2, 0xA1, 0xB1, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0xB4]
```

Obviously I have a misconception of how align works. Could anyone please clear that up?

Comment: You know `dw` is a 2-byte "word", right?  You'd get what you expected from `dd 0xa1a2`, which would have its high 2 bytes being zero.

Answer (score 4):

To get what you want you need to put an `align` directive directly in front of the `ys` data. Also, to get it to use zero bytes as alignment data you have to explicitly specify this. (The default is 90h `nop`.) Like this:

```
section .data
align 4, db 0
  xs: dw 0xA1A2
align 4, db 0
  ys: db 0xB1, 0xB2, 0xB3, 0xB4
```

This is because the directive does **not** mean "going forward, align all data to this boundary". What it does mean is, "at this particular point align the emitted data once to this boundary".

Comment: @sadElephent: Edited to add explanation.

Comment: Or even more mechanically, you can think of `align` as "emit padding here until the current position is aligned to the requested alignment."  That makes it even more clear that it doesn't interact with later lines *at all*, it just expands on its own.